# Reducing network hops with a distributed topic with ActiveMQ network of brokers

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Lets say I have a network of brokers which share a topic on which orders are published. I have two brokers one in location A and one in location B.

One of the consumers of the topic is also located in location A and is configured to connect to broker A. Both the brokers publish orders on the topic and the consumer will receive all the orders published by the two brokers.

As I understand the orders published by broker in location B will internally be passed to broker in location A by ActiveMQ and from there will be published to the consumer in location A.

Is there an easy way to publish the order from broker B directly to the consumers in location A?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - don't use a network of brokers; what you're describing is how that works (and is designed to work).

If you don't want that, instead have the consumer connect to all brokers directly and don't set them up as a network / cluster.